# App is not working after a Oreo(8.0) Update in Samsung galaxy S8

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy

Im getting this error when i start my app "All apps associated with this action have been turned off blocked or are not installed".Anyone can help me to resolve this error

**Note:I have not installed package disable pro app**

Comment: Can you show your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I have mentioned activity in AndroidManifest file like this  
  
   <activity android:name=".activity.NoticeInfoActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/TNTheme.LeftRight">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="noticeinfo" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
   </activity>

Comment: using the below method im calling all activity

 public static boolean handleAction(Context context, String action, Bundle bundle, int flags) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        if (null != bundle) {
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
        }
       context.startActivity(intent);  
        return true;
    }

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue in my app by setting the package on the intent.

e.g. intent.setPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());